# I want to apply onclick in JavaScript without touching the HTML part so that on clicking a single th tag I will get an alert message

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is my code where I am trying to make a to-do list in which due-date, edit delete and task to be completed are the headers. But I have to apply onclick handler only on due-date so that as soon as I click the duedate column I will get the alert message but the onclick should be only applied in the JavaScript part not the HTML. And I have to take help of id in thead tag.

```
var edit=function editClickHandler(){
    alert("Edit");
}
var del=function deleteClickHandler() {
    alert("DELETE");
}
var duedate1=function ddate(){
    alert("Due Date1");
}
function myFunction(x) {
    alert(x.cellIndex);
}
function init() {
    var table = document.body.children[0];
    var t1 = table.getElementsByTagName('thead');
    var t2 = t1.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var t3 = t2.getElementsByTagName('th').getElementById('ding');
    t3.onclick = duedate1;  
}
init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code would explain it better than I will write paragraphs

You were trying to access a method that did not exist, t1.getEl ... => t1 [0] .getEl

```js
var duedate1=function ddate(){
  alert("Due Date1");
 }
 
 //You form without error
 function init() {
    var table = document.body.children[0];
    var t1 = table.getElementsByTagName('thead'); // getElementsByTagName retun an object
    console.log(t1);
    var t2 = t1[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var t3 = t2[0].getElementsByTagName('th')[0]
   t3.addEventListener("click", duedate1);  
 }
 
 //Another simplified form
 function init2 () {
    document
      .getElementById("myColumnWithEvent")
      .addEventListener("click", duedate1);
 }
    
init();
init2();
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Column 1
        </th>
        <th id='myColumnWithEvent'>
          Column 2
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Loremipsum</td>
        <td>Loremipsum</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Loremipsum</td>
        <td>Loremipsum</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <table>
</html>
```

Documentation:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: thanks It's working but I don't understand the meaning of  this line of code      var t3 = t2[0].getElementsByTagName('th')[0] as here [0] is used twice.

Comment: Hi @newbie, the documentation of the getElementsByTagName method says: 

_**The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of an elements's child elements with the specified tag name, as a NodeList object. The NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The index starts at 0**._

Based on that: `t2[0].getElementsByTagName('th') // return ["0": th, "1": th#myColumnWithEvent]`
This is because within the thead element there are two elements th

Comment: Hi @Julio n this solution I have to apply more than one handler but I want to apply handler only on thead and make use of it. Like here var t1 = table.getElementsByTagName('thead'); t1.addEventListener("click", duedate1); and by the help of id in first th I need to filter the duedate column header out. How should I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById().addEventListener()` in your JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('The link was clicked!');
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="myLink">This is my link</a>
```